# PHP substr with a limit

Tags: php, string, substr, htmlspecialchars, strip-tags

I have set a limit to the string and makeing sure that it doesnt cut it off in the middle of a word, but im running into trouble here.. If the post is less than my limit of 400 signs, it will cut of the last word of my string and im not interested in that.

```
        <?php
        $limit = 400;
        if(substr($news[text], $limit, 1) != ' ' && ($l = strrpos(substr($news[text], 0, $limit), ' '))) {
            $newstext = substr($news[text], 0, $l);
            $showtext = strip_tags($newstext);
            echo htmlspecialchars_decode($showtext);
            } else {
            $newstext = substr($news[text], 0, $limit);
            $showtext = strip_tags($newstext);
            echo htmlspecialchars_decode($showtext);
        } ?>
```

Any help to this will be appreciated

In addition i would like to have "read more" button to show if the post is greater than the limit

Comment: look at what char is at position 400. it's not whitespace, then scan forward (or backward) to find  whitespace char, and split at that location instead.

Comment: You're testing whether the character at the exact position 400 is a space. What's the chance of that?

Comment: I have tried setting the limit to 500 and it still ends at the second last word. thx though

Comment: If all you are having issues with is length under 400, why not check the string length first with `strlen()`? If over 400, then use your `substr()` code?

Comment: that seems like a good idea, thanks for taking your time! Using this: 
if(strlen($news[text]) >= $limit) {}